# How to setup IE11 redirecting properly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

Can you explain me, what should do to enable redirecting on IE11? The situation is next: 
I make a request to the back-end API, that redirect me to the external server to get some data. In all browsers it works fine, but in IE11 i get either the pending request to the server, or i indeed have no request to the data-server. 
What should i do to make it work again?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code that you have worked on and the exact issue? This will help us to understand the problem in more detail.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh, in fact, I don't even have exact sample of code. The problem is in the Three.js [ImageLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/ImageLoader.js). But i cannot say it quite confidently.